# Calculate mode, so if two values, return the smaller one

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the *mode* from a table of values and return the smallest if more than one.
Example table:

```
**Results**
id  score
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   4
5   4
6   7
```

**Desired result:**

```
3
```

The following query returns 4 (the larger of the two):

```
SELECT score 
FROM Results
 GROUP BY score
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust the `ORDER BY` to handle ties:

```
SELECT score
FROM Results
GROUP BY score
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, score
LIMIT 1;
```

You need to take into account ties -- based on your problem definition.  The database puts the results of the `GROUP BY` in an arbitrary ordering when there are ties.  Even different runs could result in different values.